# NDE for QoS Flows on SUP720-3C?

Tags: qos, cisco-6500, netflow

I've setup per user Layer 2 policing on a pair of Cat6k with SUP720-3C to rate-limit wireless guest users. This is working fine and the flow table is populated as expected (with L2 QoS flows).

Now my question: Is it possible to export these flows with NetFlow? I know that I cannot use NetFlow to gather additional flows because of flow-mask collision (policing is using `src-only` and `dst-only` already), but the table is already filling up. So it should be possible that NetFlow exports these when they age out?